# How to put a cursor on certain style position according to if-else condition

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a script to check if only "allowed styles" are in a word file. Currently, I can return true or false accordingly.

However, I would also like to have the cursor on that particular style, if it is not the allowed style.

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
Function AllStylesInArray(Arr() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim doc As Document, s As Style

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    AllStylesInArray = True

    For Each s In doc.Styles
        If s.InUse = True Then
            With doc.Content.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = ""
                .Style = s
                .Execute Format:=True
                If .Found = True Then
                    AllStylesInArray = IsInArray(s.NameLocal, Arr)
                    If AllStylesInArray = False Then Exit For
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next s
End Function
```

Edit: Here, the function **IsInArray** checks whether the style is in an Array.

```
Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, Arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In Arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function
```

So, let's say the Style *test* is not in an Array but is in the word document. I want the cursor position to be at the text with style *test* . If there are more than one styles, that are not in an array, cursor can be on the first one.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is where I check if only allowed styles are used:

```
Sub StyleExists()
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Open "C:\Users\Bla\Downloads\styles.txt" For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve Arr(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, Arr(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1
MsgBox AllStylesInArray(Arr)
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:** The file *styles.txt* consists name of the styles one per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with a `Range` object (instead of `doc.Content`) the `Find` will encompass what is found. So it's simple enough to then `Select` the `Range`.

In this case, the range needs to be reset to the entire document on every iteration to ensure the entire document is searched for the styles and not just the "found" range, or from the "found" range to the end.

For example

```
Function AllStylesInArray(Arr() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim doc As Document, s As Style
    Dim rngFound as Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    AllStylesInArray = True

    For Each s In doc.Styles
        Set rngFound = doc.Content
        If s.InUse = True Then
            With rngFound.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = ""
                .Style = s
                .Execute Format:=True
                If .Found = True Then
                    AllStylesInArray = IsInArray(s.NameLocal, Arr)
                    If AllStylesInArray = False Then
                        rngFound.Select
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next s
End Function
```

Comment: @BlueMango Done, with explanation as to why that line had to move - and sorry my logic was initially so weak. I'd have seen it if I could have tested, but didn't have enough information to actually test it. Thanks for staying with me on it :-)